# I broke Scala type safety somehow

Tags: scala, type-safety

Can some explain to me how I was able to create a case class with the wrong type? Bellow the worksheet output:

```
case class OptObj(os: Option[String], s: String)
//defined class OptObj

val osCrazy: Option[Any] = Option(Option(Option(1)))
//osCrazy: Option[Any] = Some(Some(Some(1)))

def anyOpt: Option[Any] = osCrazy
//anyOpt: Option[Any]

def getOpt[T]: Option[T] = anyOpt.map(_.asInstanceOf[T])
//getOpt: [T]=> Option[T]

val o = OptObj(getOpt[String], "It has the wrong type inside, but was built!") 
//o: OptObj = OptObj(Some(Some(Some(1))),It has the wrong type inside, but was built)

o == OptObj(None,"")
//res0: Boolean = false

o == o
//res1: Boolean = true

o.os
//res2: Option[String] = Some(Some(Some(1)))

o.os.get
//java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Some cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

**The object is created with the wrong type inside**, shouldn't object creation fail? It just fails when I try to make some operation on the os attribute.

Comment: Note that you'll get a warning about an unchecked cast when you compile that code. This is exactly what that warning is warning you about.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`Any.asInstanceOf`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Any.html) explains what you are seeing. The short of it is that the code compiles due to type erasure.

> Note that the success of a cast at runtime is modulo Scala's erasure semantics. Therefore the expression `1.asInstanceOf[String]` will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime, while the expression `List(1).asInstanceOf[List[String]]` will not. In the latter example, because the type argument is erased as part of compilation it is not possible to check whether the contents of the list are of the requested type.

Comment: Still, the part that makes me wonder is the fact that I was able to create the object. So he does not type check during object creation?

Comment: That is an interesting point.  I didn't catch that nuance.   A bunch of Scala code and Google searches didn't reveal anything specific.  Someone with more knowledge will have to give better insight.